# Proving that $\min\left \{ f,g \right \}$ and $\max\left \{ f,g \right \}$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous at $x=a$ then so are the functions $\min\left \{ f,g \right \}$ and $\max\left \{ f,g \right \}$.

I know that the definition of continuity is as follows. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $E \subseteq  X$, $p \in E$ and $f:E\rightarrow Y$. We say that $f$ is continuous at point $p$ if for all $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$ such that 
$$d\left ( f(x), f(p)\right ) < \epsilon$$ for all $x \in E$ for which $d\left ( x,p \right )< \delta$.

Now to show that $\min\left \{ f,g \right \}$ is continuous at$x=a$, do I have to show something like what's below?

Want to show that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$d\left ( \min\left \{ f(x),g(x)\right \}, \min\left \{ f(a),g(a)\right \} \right )< \epsilon$$ for all $x$ for which $d\left ( x,a \right )< \delta$.

The converse applies for $\max\left \{ f,g \right \}$.

I'm not sure how to get started on either of the two.

Comment: If $f(a) < g(a)$, then there exists a neighborhood $N$ of $a$ on which $\min(f(x), g(x)) = f(x)$ for $x \in N$ (You should prove this).  Likewise if $f(a) > g(a)$.  Now what happens if $f(a) = g(a)$?

Comment: hmm I was thinking along those lines as well. More like $f(a) \geq g(a)$ and vice-versa. But isn't it obvious that for the first case, the min function will give you $f(x)$, and since $f(x)$ is continuous in the first place, the min function will also be continuous?

Comment: @OGC that's exactly his point.  So, the only situation you need to worry about is if $f(a) = g(a)$, which can be nicely handled with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you give me an idea of the $\epsilon - \delta$ argument for $f=g$ at $x=a$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard proof is to observe that
$$ \max\{f,g\}=\frac{f+g}{2}+\frac{|f-g|}{2}$$
and
$$ \min\{f,g\}=\frac{f+g}{2}-\frac{|f-g|}{2}$$
and then use the fact that sums and compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: It also suffices to note that $\max\{x,y\}$ is continuous as a map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, that works too.

Comment: @carmichael561 I'll have to use the definition of continuity though, so can I still use the standard proof?

Comment: If you need to use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition then I guess you'll have to do it directly. But if you've already proved that the sum of two continuous functions is continuous and that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, then this is the way to go.

Comment: I did the same answer on another very similar post, but I get massively downvoted. Its funny :)

Answer (score 3):

$$min\left \{ f,g \right \}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x) +g(x) -|f(x)-g(x)|)$$ and $$max\left \{ f,g \right \}(x)= \frac{1}{2}(f(x) +g(x) +|f(x)-g(x)|)$$.