# If $f,g$ are continuous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\min\{f,g\}$ and $\max\{f,g\}$ are at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ as well

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Define $\min\{f,g\}$ and $\max\{f,g\}$ as follows:
>   $$
> \max\{f,g\}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)\quad f(x)\geq g(x)\\g(x)\quad f(x)<g(x) \end{cases}
> $$$$
> \min\{f,g\}(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)\quad f(x)\leq g(x)\\g(x)\quad f(x)>g(x) \end{cases}
> $$ 
>   *(Prove/disprove)* if $f,g$ are continous at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\min\{f,g\}$ and $\max\{f,g\}$ are at $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ as well.

(*Hint:* $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}\quad \min\{a,b\}+\max\{a,b\}=a+b$ and $\max\{a,b\}-\min\{a,b\}=|a-b|$)

*Progress*:
I'm struggling applying the hint to disprove it.

Comment: The simplest way to **dis**prove a general statement is to give a counter-example.  Why do you believe it is not true?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323892/proving-that-min-left-f-g-right-and-max-left-f-g-right-are-c?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the hint, you can actually prove this fact: the function $\max(f,g)$ is indeed defined by
$$\max(f,g)(x)=\frac{|g(x)-f(x)|+f(x)+g(x)}{2},$$
and you can conclude with the fact that $x\mapsto|x|$ is a continuous function. Try to do the same with $\min$!

Geometric interpretation of the hint: take $a,b$ two points of the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Then $$c:=\frac{a+b}{2}$$ is the middle of the points $a$ and $b$, while $$v:=\frac{|b-a|}{2}$$ is the vector with the same length as the ones going from $c$ to $b$ or from $c$ to $a$, but it is oriented from left to right. By translating $c$ by $v$, you get the biggest ("rightest") point.